# Cant connect COM object.

Tags: vbscript

I have written a COM library on C++.
There is only 1 function in this library.

```
STDMETHODIMP TMyCodeBitmapGenerateImpl::GenerateMyFile(BSTR ATextToEncode,
   BSTR APathToSaveFile)
```

Library name is  **MyCode_COM_Library**

Library is registered in the system.

trying

```
DataString = "data123"
Filename = "D:\img.bmp"
with CreateObject("MyCode_COM_Library.TMyCodeBitmapGenerateImpl")
.GenerateMyFile(DataString,Filename)
end with
```

I'm getting error **Object Required**

Trying again

```
dim ws
dim wd

Set ws = CreateObject("MyCode_COM_Library.TMyCodeBitmapGenerateImpl")
Set wd = ws.GenerateMyFile(datastring, FileName)
```

same error.

In VB in References i added this library

```
Dim wd

Dim wa As MyCodeBitmapGenerate

datastring = "data123"
FileName = "D:\img123.bmp"

wd = wa.GenerateMyFile(datastring, FileName) ' the function returns int
```

After that the compilator selects

**.GenerateMyFile**

and giving error  **Expected Function or Variable**

Please help me to connect VB and my COM library.

Thank You.

Comment: Is your component properly registered? Can you see its entries in the registry? Is it a 32-bit or 64-bit component? Are you using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of CSCRIPT/WSCRIPT?

Comment: Yes, the component is registered. It is 32-bit component. I'm using 32-bit WSCRIPT

Comment: In the VB code from your original post, it doesn't look like you've created an instance of `wa`. You declared it (`Dim wa As MyCodeBitmapGenerate`) but you still need to create the object with `Set wa = New MyCodeBitmapGenerate` before you can invoke properties or methods of `wa`, like you're trying to do on the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm adding library in References and writing such code in VB than all OK

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim azclib As AztecCodeBitmapGenerate

ds = "12343445454243442Data1234567890"
fp = "D:\imgDS.bmp"

Set azclib = New AztecCodeBitmapGenerate
azclib.GenerateAztecFile ds, fp

End Sub
```

But if i'm trying to write this code in VBScript like

```
Dim dt
Dim fp

Dim we, ws

dt = "123456789"
fp = "C:\imgDT.bmp"

Set we = CreateObject("AztecCode_COM_Library.TAztecCodeBitmapGenerateImpl")

Call we.GenerateAztecFile(dt, fp)
```

then i have an error Object Required - 800A01A8 on Call we.GEnerateAztecFile (dt,fp). 
I think that the object "we" is not created but i'm not sure

Comment: If the COM library wasn't valid or didn't exist you'd get the "ActiveX component can't create object" error on your CreateObject() line. So your COM library must be properly registered. Try using the CreateObject() syntax in VB and see if it works. Does your COM class support IDispatch? You won't be able to use CreateObject() if it doesn't.

Comment: Set we = CreateObject("AztecCode_COM_Library.TAztecCodeBitmapGenerateImpl") works fine.

Comment: Yep, and it will as long as the COM library is properly registered. But as soon as you try to invoke a method or property, it uses the IDispatch interface to locate the method or property. If your COM class doesn't support IDispatch, any method or property calls will fail.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to add IDispatch to DLL Library

Comment: @Bond , Thank You! I added IDispatch interface and now it works

Comment: Good to hear. Please upvote the comment that helped you most so that others can learn as well.